# Does BackendConfig override the console when configuring IAP for a HTTPS resource?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iap

I have an API protected by IAP on GCP which is configured via a backendconfig. It works fine. As well as turning IAP on/off via backendconfig, you can do the same via the console UI.

If my backendconfig says IAP is enabled, then I disable it using the console, it does get disabled for about 10 minutes then something appears to re-enable it again.

This looks to me like a periodic background process is ensuring the backendconfig values are the source of truth and so reverting the console change.

I can't find any documentation about this behaviour, can anyone confirm what's going on here? Also if the change is going to be reverted can the console not just disallow the change in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the [GKE Ingress controller](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)? The Ingress controller treats its state as authoritative, and will make whatever GCE API calls it needs to make so that your GCE resource configuration matches that state.